# Solved. Dark theme flair not being updated while the others are.

Tags: support, bug, status-norepro

I noticed that the dark flair theme is the only one that has not been updated, as shown in this picture from my profile:

[image]

It must be emphasized that this dark theme flair is the one I display on my personal website.

Is it a well known bug? How can it be fixed? Thank you in advance for your feedback!

**Edit.** For some reason, this is now fixed.